# Get an item within an arraylist of an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListPractice {
   public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        arr.add(10);
        arr.add(20);
        // arr is now [10,20]
        ArrayList arr2 = new ArrayList();
        arr2.add(new ArrayList(arr));
        arr2.add(30);
        // arr2 is now [[10,20],30]
        System.out.println(arr2.get(0)); // Prints out [10,20]
   }
}
```

I can print out the first element of *arr2*. But how can I print out the first element of the first element? (I want to print out 10 from *arr2*.)

Comment: If you're using Java 5 or later, please consider using `ArrayList<Integer> arr` etc. so that you can make use of the type information. The concept is "Generics".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **cast arr2.get(0) to ArrayList** so you can call the **get method** on it (your ArrayList ArrayList arr = new ArrayList(); is not typed - so it holds instances of Object).

Like this:

```
package test;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListPractice {
   public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        arr.add(10);
        arr.add(20);
        // arr is now [10,20]
        ArrayList arr2 = new ArrayList();
        arr2.add(new ArrayList(arr));
        arr2.add(30);
        // arr2 is now [[10,20],30]
        System.out.println(((ArrayList)arr2.get(0)).get(0)); // Prints out [10]
   }
}
```

Comment: You should use the generic way.